# How to show content that changing time-to-time on a HTML Document

Tags: php, html, data-transfer, data-transfer-process

I want to show content that changing (Updating) time to time. For an example, Show Stack Overflow's Recent Questions. It changes within seconds sometimes. To do this, Should i go to website everytime, Copy code from source page and paste it on my document? It is very bad method and can't do this everytime. Have their a Easy way to show the content correctly without copy/pasting or showing in a I-frame. Also i want to include the questions into document without sidebar or navigation and with only questions, authors, times, other importants and SO logo on top.

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<i class="fa fa-stack-overflow" id="logo">
<h1>Stack Overflow - Latest Questions</h1>
.... What should include? ....
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

What is the Most Easiest Way to do this? If the question is difficult to understand or Want more details, Please comment before down-voting! Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the website for which you're wanting to do this. If they have an API, like in your example ([SO has an API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs)), then you should use that.

Probably you would want to call that website's API on your server, and then [periodically](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) call your server's API to get the most recent data from the site you're interested.

Comment: Hi! Can i use this method to build Extensions and Mobile Apps? Also if a Website haven't an API, Can i create one or the Site Owner should develop one?